# how to return a value from this try catch function in java?

Tags: java, class, return

so i have this class

```
public static String ip (String url){

try {


    String webPagea = url;
    URL urla = new URL(webPagea);
    URLConnection urlConnectiona = urla.openConnection();
    InputStream isa = urlConnectiona.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isra = new InputStreamReader(isa);

    int numCharsReada;
    char[] charArraya = new char[1024];
    StringBuffer sba = new StringBuffer();
    while ((numCharsReada = isra.read(charArraya)) > 0) {
        sba.append(charArraya, 0, numCharsReada);
    }
    String resulta = sba.toString();
    return resulta;


} catch (Exception e)

{



}
    **(compile error)
       }
```

and i want the above to return the resulta string when called from another class like below:

```
private class t1 implements Runnable{
    public void run() {

   String getip= ip("http://google.com");
     }
```

but i get compile error that i didn't add a return statement above where the 2 stars are.

Also in general when i define a string within a try catch like above i cant access it outside the try/catch what am i doing wrong ?

example:

```
  public void haha(String data)
{
    try {

   string test="test6";

  } catch (Exception e)

  }

 string vv=test;   <--test cannot be found


}
```

I want to emphasize i want to get the output of the page not the source code

if the website outputs text i want just the text not the html code

cheers

Comment: Your method is returning a String. so try to add in your catch: return "your error..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the string `resulta` is within the bounds of the `try` block. Modify you rcode to have the string `resulta` declared outside the `try` block, like this:

```
public static String ip (String url){
String resulta = "";
try {
    String webPagea = url;
    URL urla = new URL(webPagea);
    URLConnection urlConnectiona = urla.openConnection();
    InputStream isa = urlConnectiona.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isra = new InputStreamReader(isa);

    int numCharsReada;
    char[] charArraya = new char[1024];
    StringBuffer sba = new StringBuffer();
    while ((numCharsReada = isra.read(charArraya)) > 0) {
        sba.append(charArraya, 0, numCharsReada);
    }
    resulta = sba.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
    return resulta;
}
```